Automatic switching between two 24V power supplies
I am trying to make a 24V version of this circuit.
Circuit diagram:

I have modeled the primary power source as pulsing so I can see the effect of it being switched off.
The output simulation looks great with a very small voltage ripple.

When prototyping this on a breadboard using an IRF9540 PMOS, the circuit responds as simulated when both sources are connected. When the primary source is disconnected the voltage is limited to around 20V. I believe this is because the rated VGS voltage is +-20V. I am unable to find any PMOS with higher VGS rating.
Does anyone have any thoughts/solutions?
Unlinked to this issue I was wondering if I could replace the diode with a MOSFET with a shorted gate source to reduce power loss over the diode in order to reduce the voltage drop further. Would this be a good idea?

Why not just 2 diodes, and forget about the FETs?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode-or_circuit

Which is the "primary" source?

V1 is the primary source, by switching it on and off every 2 seconds I am simulating it being removed from the circuit, and then reattached.

I looked at using an OR- ing circuit but as these 2 sources will be batteries, I want the secondary battery (V2) to be isolated when V1 is pluged in. As I understood if both are connected then an Or-ing circuit will draw power from both V1 and V2.

Actually, you're already using the solution given by vu2nan without realising it because M1 is the wrong way round and its body diode will be forward biased all the time.

I know this is an old thread, but I don't see an answer to one of his questions.
As above, reverse the drain and source connections for M1.

I am unable to find any PMOS with higher VGS rating.

Once the connections are corrected, add a 12 V zener diode between the gate and source.  R1 already is there to limit the diode current.  Note the power dissipation in R1.  If a 1/4 W part is too big for your assembly, increase R1 to something in the 2.2K to 4.7 K range.

Here's a solution using only two Schottky diodes.

The output voltage of the primary power supply unit is to be set marginally higher than that of the other.

Will this circuit completely isolate the secondary battery V2, when V1 is connected though? As these will be batteries I do not want V2 to have run down before it is needed.

@wrprice Define completely. All solutions will have reverse leakage. How much can you tolerate?

@winny when prototyping the original circuit around 5mA was being drawn from the secondary power supply (V1), and the rest (around 0.45A) from the primary power source. Ideally I would be looking for something around this.

@wrprice Very good. Any Schottky diode would do.

Hi wrprice, With this circuit the secondary power supply will take over only when the primary one fails.  In the case of  two batteries, at any point of time either one or the other will cater to the load depending on which voltage is higher. Both will be in circuit when the voltages are equal. There is no question of only one battery being in circuit and the other taking over after the first has run down.

Thank you! I have simulated it and it works I will check it physically to see if it acts the same in real life.

Hi wrprice, Have fun!
